# How to parse the meta keywords of chinese with java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have code below, but it looks it parse keyword in wrong way for chinese. How can i change it?

**OUTPUT:**

```
keyword：test
keyword：中
keyword：文
keyword：U
keyword：I
keyword：素
keyword：材
```

**Should be below:**

```
keyword：test
keyword：中文
keyword：UI
keyword：素材
```

This is my code:

```
public class test {
  public static final Pattern KEYWORDS_REGEX =
      Pattern.compile("[^\\s,](?:[^,]+[^\\s,])?");
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String keywords = "test, 中文, UI, 素材";


      Matcher matcher = KEYWORDS_REGEX.matcher(keywords);

      while (matcher.find()) {
        String s = matcher.group();
        System.out.println("keyword：" +s);
      }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think in this case it'd be alot easier to just use [explode](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: it's NOT PHP, it's java.

Comment: Sorry, String.split() then... Time for me to sleep I guess.

Comment: String[]   strSplit=keywords.split( "(\\s*,\\s*|\\s+)"); 
like above?  but how can i remove the repeated one or empty string?

Comment: @Kisaro it exists in Apache Commons as extra utility

Comment: String[] strSplit = keywords.split(','); When outputting parts do strSplit[n].trim(); to get rid of all spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with Chinese characters, the problem is with keywords that are two characters long. (That's why it affects `UI` as well.) This regex:

```
[^\s,](?:[^,]+[^\s,])?
```

allows two possibilities:

```
[^\s,]                <-- exactly one character
[^\s,][^,]+[^\s,]     <-- three or more characters
```

so any keywords with two characters will not match, so they get split into single-character keywords.

You could fix your regex by changing `[^,]+` to `[^,]*`, but I'm inclined to agree with the spirit of Kisaro's comment above; I think you'd be better off using [`Pattern.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
private static final KEYWORD_SPLITTER = Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*");

for(final String s : KEYWORD_SPLITTER.split(keywords))
    System.out.println("keyword:" + s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be `\\w` to match words.  This should generate the desired output.

Also since someone suggested explode:  [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: No.  And you mean `\w` not `\\w`.  In any event, `\w` will only work here if used in conjunction with Java 7’s `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag; otherwise the Java `Pattern` class fails to conform with the formal requirements of [UTS#18: Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/) needed for minimal Unicode functionality. The error here is that without that flag, Java’s antemillennial `\w` does not meet the requirements of [RL1.2a Compatibility Properties](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties).